# Over-collection of FICA (social security and medicare) taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, payroll-taxes

I have been non-resident alien in the last year 2018, and I have switched to a new employer in the last few months of last year.

Last month, I discovered that my new employer was collecting FICA (medicare and social security). When you are a non-resident alien, you are exempt from FICA.

I have asked them for refunding the over-collected taxes, they refused saying that I did not inform them of my filing status in 2018.

How to get the money back in this case? Does the IRS refund it?

Best Regards,

Comment: How _long_ have you been a nonresident alien?  After four years (or is it five?), nonresident aliens are considered to be _tax residents_ of the US (even though their _visa_ status is nonresident alien) and therefore liable to pay SS and Medicare taxes.

Comment: "When you are a non-resident alien, you are exempt from FICA." Not generally. Only nonresident aliens in [a few statuses](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-student-liability-for-social-security-and-medicare-taxes), including F1 and J1, are exempt from FICA. Nonresident aliens working in other statuses are still subject to FICA. Please tell us what status you were in.

Comment: I am J1 since 2016. But for 2018 I have spent ~7 months outside the US, hence I don't satisfy the substantial presence test.  @user102008

Comment: @DilipSarwate please see my answer above

Answer (score 1):

[The IRS](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/social-security-tax-medicare-tax-and-self-employment) and the [University of Texas](https://world.utexas.edu/isss/ssn-tax/refunds) each have articles that explain the procedure for requesting a refund of FICA taxes that were mistakenly withheld.

First, they suggest requesting a refund from your employer, which you’ve already done.

If the employer won’t or can’t give you a refund, then you need to get a written statement from your employer explaining why they cannot give you a refund. You send that statement to the IRS along with [Form 843](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-843), [Form 8316](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8316.pdf), and a bunch of other supporting documentation proving your exempt status.